# Upgrade php version on symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Currently, I have a problem with my Symfony project because I made the php update. And now, I can not use my compose in the folder of my project anymore. How can I remedy this problem ?

I installed PHP version 7.3.4.
I have version 1.8.5 of composer.

Error Image:

[image: Error]

Comment: Disabling JIT should do the trick. Set `pcre.jit=0` in php.ini

Comment: Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can disable JIT like @Sondre Edvardsen said but that will it disable for all projects.

You can also disable it for the single command with:

```
php -d pcre.jit=0 composer.phar {...rest of your command}
```

Comment: Thx for your help i disable pcre.jit